# ListView Control Windows API - CheckAll - CheckCount?

Tags: listview, vb6

I have a VB6 project that I am switching from using ListBoxes to using ListViews. The Lists have the checkbox style. I am looking for Windows API Messages to send to the ListView that specify:

- Check All
- Uncheck All
- Checked Count

This was easy for the ListBox as Selected is the same thing as Checked. Not true for the ListView.

So something like this except for CHECKED not SELECTED:

```
Private Const LVM_FIRST As Long = &H1000
Private Const LVM_GETITEMCOUNT As Long = (LVM_FIRST + 4)
Private Const LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT As Long = (LVM_FIRST + 50)
Private Const LV_SETSEL = &H1000 + 43

Private Function ListViewSelectedCount(ByRef LV As ListView) As Long
    ListViewSelectedCount = SendMessage(LV.hwnd, LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT, 0, 0)
End Function

Private Sub ListViewSelectAll(ThisBox As ListView)
    Dim LV As LV_ITEM
    LV.mask = &H8
    LV.State = True
    LV.stateMask = &H2

    Call SendMessage(ThisBox.hwnd, LV_SETSEL, ByVal -1, LV)
End Sub
```

I did find a listing of ListView messages: http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/comctl/lvmembers.htm
but nothing there seemed to be what I needed.

Comment: Check out the [Community Additions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761196(v=vs.85).aspx) for LVM_SETITEMSTATE on MSDN.  It has an example of how to set the checked/unchecked state for a specific index.  **According to the docs above, however, you can pass -1 to affect them all at the same time.**  As far as I can tell, though, there's no way to get a count of checked items back.  You'd have to iterate over every item and check its state, accumulating as you go.

Comment: Well, part of the way is better than where I was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have to use the Windows API Messages to set the selected flag.  I am making the assumption that you are using the ListView from the Microsoft Windows Common Controls.  If you are then you could use the following code:

```
Public Sub SetSelected(ByVal blnCheck As Boolean)
Dim lviItem As ListItem

    For Each lviItem In ListView.ListItems
        lviItem.Checked = blnCheck
    Next

    Set lviItem = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function CountChecked() As Long
Dim lngCount    As Long
Dim lviItem     As ListItem

    For Each lviItem In ListView.ListItems
        If lviItem.Checked Then
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    Set lviItem = Nothing

    CountChecked = lngCount

End Function
```

Call the SetSelected with a true or false and will select / deselect all, the second function will return the count.  You should rename the ListView bit of the code to be the name of your ListView.  If you wanted to make it more generic you could pass the listview into the sub and function and that code would look something like this:

```
Public Sub SetSelected(ByRef lvwToChange As ListView, ByVal blnCheck As Boolean)
Dim lviItem As ListItem

    For Each lviItem In lvwToChange.ListItems
        lviItem.Checked = blnCheck
    Next

    Set lviItem = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function CountChecked(ByRef lvwToCount As ListView) As Long
Dim lngCount    As Long
Dim lviItem     As ListItem

    For Each lviItem In lvwToCount.ListItems
        If lviItem.Checked Then
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    Set lviItem = Nothing

    CountChecked = lngCount

End Function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I have to use the API, no. But looping through the contents of the control is slower for the ListBox and I am assuming it would be slower for the ListView as well. (Why send N windows messages if there exists a single message that returns what I need? O(N) vs O(1)) Hence my question.